# How can I check if pytest-django is installed and why doesn't client fixture work?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I installed `pytest-django` with pip and made a test file, which uses the `client` fixture as per the [docs](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#client-django-test-client), but running this gives me `fixture 'client' not found`. Here's my `test_homepage.py`:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_homepage(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you are running the tests? And what version of pytest are you running `pytest.__version__`

Comment: Can you also run `py.test --traceconfig` and add the output to your answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer as a result of your last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have `pytest-django` installed. I installed `pytest-django` on my machine and ran a simple project.

1. Install `pip install pytest-django`
2. Setup and run my sample test:

   ```
   platform linux -- Python 3.4.3 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2
   rootdir: /home/matt/projects/test_app/src, inifile: pytest.ini
   plugins: django
   collected 1 items 

   tests/test_example.py .
   ```

   Sample code:

   ```
   import pytest

   @pytest.mark.django_db
   def test_something(client):
           response = client.get('/')
           assert  response.status_code == 200
   ```

   Note the plugins listed and the code works.
3. Uninstall for the sake of testing I am going to remove `pip uninstall pytest-django`
4. Once again run the tests `py.test`

   ```
   platform linux -- Python 3.4.3 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2
   rootdir: /home/matt/projects/test_app/src, inifile: pytest.ini
   collected 1 items 

   tests/test_example.py E

   ==================================== ERRORS ====================================
   _______________________ ERROR at setup of test_something _______________________
   file /home/matt/projects/test_app/src/tests/test_example.py, line 3
   @pytest.mark.django_db
   def test_something(client):
       fixture 'client' not found
       available fixtures: tmpdir, pytestconfig, recwarn, capsys, capfd, monkeypatch
       use 'py.test --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
   ```

   Now we can see the same error you are stating in your project.

So, if I were you I would completely remove `pytest` and `pytest-django` from your environment then re-install. It looks like either `pytest-django` has not been installed or that the plugins are not being detected for some reason.

If this does not help solve the project your other option is to run `py.test --traceconfig` this will give you a more verbose output of the run process. Do this then add the output to your question.